# Flask project in Visual Studio 2015: how to specify port number?

Tags: python, visual-studio, flask, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

How can I specify the port number in a Flask python project under Visual Studio 2015, so that when it starts it always uses the same port?

My startup file (app.py) looks like this:

```
from svc.svc import app
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

So I guess that somehow I need to specify the SERVER_PORT environment variable for the debugger process, but I cannot find any option for it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to set the environment variable, right?

Comment: @Andy: yes, the value in the end is taken from the environment variable, which has a different value each time I start the debugger.

Comment: Why are you using VS2015 for python development?

Comment: @nucleon: why not :) ?

Comment: Maybe I should give it a try. Was sticking to pydev for eclipse.

Comment: @nucleon: Eclipse was my favorite editor (besides vim) when I was working on Linux, but on Windows I always use VS. In the end it's a matter of habits and personal preferences, but I think the Python Tools for VS are pretty cool. You can always try the VS 2015 Community Edition, which is free and has all the most important features.

Comment: I'm just not used to the direction Microsoft is going there. I'll give it a try if I have time, since in PyDev I'm having some issues with syntax highlighting using SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right click on the project name and choose "Properties".
Then, click on "Debug" and you will see a "Port Number" and "Environment" section in which you will be able to set the port number and any other environment variables.

[image: Port number and environment variables]

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that -_-

Comment: Thanks for such a simple and quick solution.

Comment: Glad I could help :)